# How to store json as relational data in an Oracle table from java as a column?

Tags: java, jdbc, oracle12c

I am trying to figure out how i can have a row with an id and a json data in oracle 12.
Examples there are means to store json in oracle 12 as "is_json" constraint but could not figure how i will send the object through java ;as a string or json object?.
Can i use SODA jar to store both normal row data(id) and a JSON together?
How to fetch(query) IS_JSON constraint column in java?

Comment: For the sake of a fast, maybe uncomplete answer. Yes you send the json object as string and save it into your database as Varchar, as long as it wont be to big. The IS_JSON constraint is i guess an option you can activate in your table, which checks while inserting or altering if the given string is a json struct. If not it will throw an error. There should be nothing to do on the java backend.

Answer (score 1):

Would need to know more details about your complete use-case.

But, in general, you have two options:

(1) You can use SODA Java. That'll create the a collection. Under the covers, collection is backed by a regular table which will have an ID column (for key), and JSON_DOCUMENT column for JSON content (that's by default, column names can be changed if desired thru custom collection metadata passed to createCollection). That underlying collection table is visible/accessible from SQL as well. By default, JSON_DOCUMENT is a BLOB, but, thru custom collection metadata, you can request VARCHAR2 or CLOB storage. That's all very easy to do in a couple of lines of code.

See an example for getting started:
https://github.com/oracle/soda-for-java/blob/master/doc/Getting-started-example.md

SODA basically gives you an abstraction of NoSQL document collections, and it's very easy to work with in Java. It saves you from having to code SQL over JDBC, and deal with low level things like bind variables, etc.

(2) If SODA is not the right abstraction for your use-case, you can use JSON support in Oracle and JDBC (that's exactly what SODA is using under the covers as well). You'd create a regular table with a column for ID and a column for JSON. You'd put an 'is json' constraint on your JSON column when defining this table. The JSON column can be of type BLOB (recommended), VARCHAR2, or CLOB. With BLOB, as opposed to VARCHAR2, JSON size is not limited to 32k, and encoding conversions are avoided.

Then you'd bind/fetch JSON data as usual with JDBC (just like how you'd usually bind/fetch non-JSON data into/from BLOB/VARCHAR2/CLOB, nothing really changes). You can use various JSON operators (json_value, json_table, and so on) in your SQL queries that you issue over JDBC, in order to work with your JSON data.